# Make two actions work simultaneously - react native and redux

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux

I've a button that sends two actions. First one adds the user infos in an array if certain condition is met and 2nd one sends the data to the server.
Since both actions are in onPress function, the 2nd action doesn't wait till it adds up the infos in an array. Henceforth, it always sends empty array.
How can I make this two actions work simultaneously.

```
<TouchableOpacity
    onPress={() => {
      if (true) {
        this.props.AuthUserInfoGet(SignUpName, SignUpDesignation, SignUpEmail, SignUpMobileNo); //calculates & return SignUpUsers
      }
      this.props.SignUpCheck(SignUpUsers); //upload SignUpUsers but SignUpCheck is always empty here
    }}
>
      <Text>Upload</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  const {SignUpUsers} = state.Auth;
  //it gives an empty array first and then expected value
  console.log('SignUpUsersz', SignUpUsers);

  return {SignUpUsers};
};
```

Action:

```
export const AuthUserInfoGet = (SignUpName, SignUpDesignation, SignUpEmail, SignUpMobileNo) => {
  return ({
    type: SIGN_UP_USER_INFO_GET,
    payloadName: SignUpName,
    payloadDesignation: SignUpDesignation,
    payloadEmail: SignUpEmail,
    payloadMobile: SignUpMobileNo,
  });
}

export const SignUpCheck = (userInfo) => {
    console.log('userInfo', userInfo); // userInfo is always empty
}
```

Reducer:

```
const INITIAL_STATE = { SignUpUsers: [] }

case SIGN_UP_USER_INFO_GET:
  return { ...state, SignUpUsers: [...state.SignUpUsers, {member_name: actions.payloadName, designation: actions.payloadDesignation,
    email: actions.payloadEmail, mobile_number: actions.payloadMobile}] };
```

Comment: It sounds more like you want the actions to complete synchronously (as in one finishes and then the other begins). Is this right?

Comment: yeahh, one finishes and update the state, then send that state to another action.

Comment: Gotcha, I just wrote you a solution below but just to be sure, are you using functional or class component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your current Redux-structure, I think what makes the most sense to use the `componentDidUpdate` life-cycle method.

The main reason is because your component ultimately needs to get updated data from Redux via `props` and needs to re-render. When you execute the first action, that user-data coming from the API is not immediately available in the current call-stack, so you'll always be passing an empty array (given your initial value of `SignUpUsers: []`)

Note that most React-Redux flows follow this path:

**`User-Event -> Action-Creator -> API (Data) -> Redux -> Component`**

Your click-event is at step 1 and triggers this action: `this.props.AuthUserInfoGet(...args)`

But React/Redux needs to go through that entire flow before you can use the new data.

This is where the `componentDidUpdate()` event comes in-handy because you can write logic when the component is re-rendered by new props or state.

Something like this would totally work:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps){
   if(prevProps.SignUpUsers.length !== this.props.SignUpUsers.length){
      //execute action
      this.props.SignUpCheck(this.props.SignUpUsers)
   }
}
```

Comment: Hi, but this action (this.props.SignUpCheck) should only execute when the button is clicked.

Comment: @AmritaStha I mean that's true, but at the speed at which these re-renders execute, the user should not notice any lag from their input to the event. The fact is that you still need the data that's acquired from "AuthUserInfoGet" before you can execute the "SignUpCheck". Have you had a chance to test it :)

Answer (score 0):

For that I would suggest you take a look at [redux-thunk](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk) middleware.

> Redux Thunk [middleware](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/blob/master/docs/advanced/Middleware.md) allows you to write action creators that return a function instead of an action. The thunk can be used to delay the dispatch of an action, or to dispatch only if a certain condition is met. The inner function receives the store methods `dispatch` and `getState` as parameters.

And based on your example, the code will end up like this:

```
<TouchableOpacity 
  onPress={() => this.props.uploadSignUpUsers(SignUpName, SignUpDesignation, SignUpEmail, SignUpMobileNo)}>

  <Text>Upload</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  const { Auth: { SignUpUsers } } = state;

  return { SignUpUsers };
}
```

Actions:

```
export const SIGN_UP_GET_USER_INFO_SUCCESS = "SIGN_UP_GET_USER_INFO_SUCCESS";
export const SIGN_UP_UPLOAD_SUCCESS = "SIGN_UP_UPLOAD_SUCCESS";

export const uploadSignUpUsers = (SignUpName, SignUpDesignation, SignUpEmail, SignUpMobileNo) => {
   return async (dispatch, getState) => {

       // here you can make the api call or any other async calculations
       const { data: AuthUserInfo, error } = await api.post(SignUpName, SignUpDesignation, SignUpEmail, SignUpMobileNo);

       dispatch({
           type: SIGN_UP_GET_USER_INFO_SUCCESS,
           payloadName: AuthUserInfo.SignUpName,
           payloadDesignation: AuthUserInfo.SignUpDesignation,
           payloadEmail: AuthUserInfo.SignUpEmail,
           payloadMobile: AuthUserInfo.SignUpMobileNo,
       });

       const { Auth: { SignUpUsers } } = getState()

       // and now you can upload your SignUpUsers
       const { data: uploadData, error } = await.api.post(SignUpUsers)

       dispatch({
           type: SIGN_UP_UPLOAD_SUCCESS,
           ...uploadData // spread upload data to make it available in reducers 
       });
    }
}
```

Reducer:

```
const INITIAL_STATE = { SignUpUsers: [] }

case SIGN_UP_GET_USER_INFO_SUCCESS: {
    const { payloadName, payloadDesignation, payloadEmail, payloadMobile } = actions
    return { 
        ...state, 
        SignUpUsers: [ ...state.SignUpUsers, { 
            member_name: payloadName, 
            designation: payloadDesignation, 
            email: payloadEmail, 
            mobile_number: payloadMobile 
        }] 
    }
}
```